# Getting error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): api_call4.json is not a function" even when error is caught in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

While fetching the weather api, if disconnection occurs, error is thrown which is caught, and few seconds later the error is displayed on screen which is quite unpleasant. No idea of resolving this error.

1. App.js file

```
const api_call4 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?` + 
`city=${city}&key=${API_KEY3}`).catch(error => toast.error('No Data Received',error))
const data4 = await api_call4.json();
console.log('DATA CURRENT', data4)
```

As you can see above error is caught, but still error is diplayed. Please see the image below. What is the best solution...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your flow to ensure that your api call is successful.  One way would be to use try/catch blocks since you're using async/await.  Something like:

```
try {
  const api_call4 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?` + 
    `city=${city}&key=${API_KEY3}`)
  const data4 = await api_call4.json();
  console.log('DATA CURRENT', data4)
} 
catch(error) {
  toast.error('No Data Received',error)
}
```